# Python - Generate a 32 bit random int with arguments

Tags: python, random, header

I need to generate a 32 bit random int but depending of some arguments. The idea is generate a unique ID for each message to send through a own P2P network. To generate it, I would like as arguments: my IP and the time stamp. My question is, how can I generate this 32 bit random int from these arguments?

Thanks again!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Generate a random number that is unique in some way? A 32 bit number isn't wide enough to be unique across all IP numbers (which are 32 bit to begin with) and still be reasonably random.

Comment: 32bits is would be a VERY big number indeed.

Comment: It is a own protocol where one of the headers is message_id, and the length is 32 bit. I thought to use those arguments because the message_id must be unique in whole the network (arround 40 hosts) and also unique within all the messages that I send. I will send it in a packet with more headers and also a body.

Comment: It seems like what you want is not a random number, but a hash mapping.  I guess it comes down to: if an ip and datetime d are supplied and generate a random number z.  Suppose the same ip and datetime are given to the algorithm again do you want a different 32 bit number?

Comment: But, it is impossible have the same ip and datatime, isn't it? at least the datatime should be different in each moment, but even if I pass it again the same arguments, should be the same result... Yes what I need is a hash map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using some sort of hash.  There are many possible hashes, the [FNV hash](http://isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/fnv/) comes in a variety of sizes and is fast.  If you want something cryptographically secure it will be a lot slower.  You may need to add a counter: 1, 2, 3, 4... to ensure that you do not get duplicate hashes within the same time stamp.

Comment: This is exactly what I need, but, I have to install a external library... is for an assignment in my University, I do not know if I can use external librarys... If I can, it is the solution!

Comment: The FNV hash is just a few lines of code.  You should be able to code it yourself.  If not, just pick another simple hash that is doable in Python.  There are many simple non-crypto hashes out there.

Comment: this will generate collisions after 65000 messages or so.

Comment: Only if you use the 32 bit FNV, as specified in the question.  Larger sizes of FNV are specified up to 1024 bit overkill.  All good 32 bit hashes will have collisions at the same rate.

Answer (score 3):

here's a list of options with their associated problems:

1. use a random number.  you will get a collision (non-unique value) in about half the bits (this is the "birthday collision").  so for 32 bits you get a collision after 2*16 messages.  if you are sending less than 65,000 messages this is not a problem, but 65,000 is not such a big number.
2. use a sequential counter from some service.  this is what twitter's snowflake does (see another answer here).  the trouble is supplying these across the net.  typically with distributed systems you give each agent a set of numbers (so A might get 0-9, B get's 10-19, etc) and they use those numbers then request a new block.  that reduces network traffic and load on the service providing numbers.  but this is complex.
3. generate a hash from some values that will be unique.  this sounds useful but is really no better than (1), because your hashes are going to collide (i explain why below).  so you can hash IP address and timestamp, but all you're doing is generating 32 bit random numbers, in effect (the difference is that you can reproduce these values, but it doesn't seem like you need that functionality anyway), and so again you'll have a collisions after 65,000 messages or so, which is not much.
4. be smarter about generating ids to guarantee uniqueness.  the problem in (3) is that you are hashing more than 32 bits, so you are compressing information and getting overlaps.  instead, you could explicitly manage the bits to avoid collisions.  for example, number each client for 16 bits (allows up to 65,000 clients) and then have each client user a 16 bit counter (allows up to 65,000 messages *per client* which is a big improvement on (3)).  those won't collide because each is guaranteed unique, but you have a lot of limits in your system and things are starting to get complex (need to number clients and store counter state per client).
5. use a bigger field.  if you used 64 bit ids then you could just use random numbers because collisions would be once every 2**32 messages, which is practically never (1 in 4,000,000,000).  or you could join ip address (32 bits) with a 32 bit timestamp (but be careful - that probably means no more than 1 message per second from a client).  the only drawback is slightly larger bandwidth, but in most cases ids are much smaller than payloads.

personally, i would use a larger field and random numbers - it's simple and works (although good random numbers are an issue in, say, embedded systems).

finally, if you need the value to be "really" random (because, for example, ids are used to decide priority and you want things to be fair) then you can take one of the solutions above  with deterministic values and re-arrange the bits to be pseudo-random.  for example, reversing the bits in a counter may well be good enough (compare lsb first).

Answer (score 1):

Did you try looking into Twitter's [Snowflake](https://github.com/twitter/snowflake/)? There is a Python wrapper for it.